# How do I configure Mathematica so that the "font" window opens with a given key press?

Tags: fonts, configuration

Is there any way I can configure the keys in Mathematica so that I can open the "font" window with a single key press? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Alt-R-F opens it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single key combination change

```
    MenuItem["&Font...", "FontPanel"]
```

to e.g.

```
  MenuItem["&Font...", "FontPanel",MenuKey["k", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}]]
```

in the system file

C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\13.3\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\TextResources\Windows\MenuSetup.tr